# CLI-Client for interacting with daemon

Tags: python, design-patterns, console, ipc

I have a daemon which I am able to interact with through a cli-client. The daemon will perform some tasks in future e.g. monitoring the rate at which files are added to a directory.

Right now when I add a new function I need to write

1. The function I would like to trigger
2. A message format which the client can send to the daemon to execute the function
3. A function in the client which takes the users command line argument and turns them in to a string which is sent to the daemon

Is there a better way of designing this interaction?

**Below is the daemon**

```
##################### Daemon ##################################

##################### Just for context ########################
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener

class Nark:
    def __init__(self, folder_path):
        self.path = folder_path
    
    def change_path(self, folder_path):
        self.path = folder_path
        
    def get_path(self):
        return self.path

class NarkPool:
    def __init__(self):
        self.narkdict = {}
    
    def add_nark(self, name, path):
        self.narkdict[name] = Nark(path)
        
    def remove_nark(self, name):
        self.narkdict.pop(name)
    
    def change_path(self, name, path):
        self.narkdict[name].change_path(path)
    
    def get_path(self, name):
        return self.narkdict[name].get_path()
    
    def get_names(self):
        return list(self.narkdict.keys())

################### Important Part Below #############################
    
address = ('localhost', 7389)
listener = Listener(address)

narks = NarkPool()

while True:
    conn = listener.accept()
    print ('connection accepted from', listener.last_accepted)
    while True:
        msg = conn.recv()
        command = msg.split(' ')  # command input would be eg. add <name> <path>

        # Manually define action to be taken based on each command

        if command[0] == 'add' : narks.add_nark(command[1], command[2])
        if command[0] == 'remove' : narks.remove(command[1])
        if command[0] == 'change_path': narks.change_path(command[1], command[2])
        if command[0] == 'get_path' :
            conn.send(narks.get_path(command[1]))
        if command[0] == 'list':
            conn.send(narks.get_names())
            
        
        if msg :
            conn.close()
            break

listener.close()
```

**And here is the client:**

```
################# Client ##########################
import click
from multiprocessing.connection import Client

adress = ('localhost', 7389)

@click.group()
def cli():
    pass

# for each possible daemon command create a function which
# takes respective user input and sends it to daemon
@cli.command()
@click.argument('name')
@click.argument('path')
def add_nark(name, path):
    conn = Client(adress)
    conn.send(f'add {name} {path}')
    conn.close()

@cli.command()
@click.argument('name')
def remove_nark(name):
    conn = Client(adress)
    conn.send(f'remove {name}')
    conn.close()

@cli.command()
@click.argument('name')
@click.argument('path')
def change_path(name, path):
    conn = Client(adress)
    conn.send(f'change_path {name} {path}')
    conn.close()

@cli.command()
@click.argument('name')
def get_path(name):
    conn = Client(adress)
    conn.send(f'get_path {name}')
    msg = False
    while not msg:
        msg = conn.recv()
    print(msg)
    conn.close()

@cli.command()
def list_runs():
    conn = Client(adress)
    conn.send(f'list')
    msg = False
    while not msg:
        msg = conn.recv()
    print(msg)
    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe its not the best approach, but it gets the work done:

## Intended approach

Instead of having to declare/modify/delete functions every time a command is added/changed/deleted, the idea is to have a list with all command, and then create the corresponding cli commands dynamically.

This way, we could say the commands in your post could be represented as:

```py
from collections import namedtuple

Command = namedtuple(
    'Command',
    (
        'cli_command',
        'serv_command',
        'args',
        'request_responde_and_show_it'
    )
)

COMMANDS = (
    Command(
        cli_command='add_nark',
        serv_command='add',
        args=('name', 'path'),
        request_responde_and_show_it=False
    ),
    Command(
        cli_command='remove_nark',
        serv_command='remove',
        args=('name',),
        request_responde_and_show_it=False
    ),
    Command(
        cli_command='change_path',
        serv_command='change_path',
        args=('name', 'path'),
        request_responde_and_show_it=False
    ),
    Command(
        cli_command='get_path',
        serv_command='get_path',
        args=('name',),
        request_responde_and_show_it=True
    ),
    Command(
        cli_command='list_runs',
        serv_command='list',
        args=(),
        request_responde_and_show_it=True
    ),
)
```

Now, lets review step by step how we could dynamically declare the cli commands.

## Common structure

All of these functions have pretty much the same body, which could be made generic as such:

```py
command = 'add'
args = ('name', 'path')
request_responde_and_show_it = False
with Client(ADDRESS) as conn:
    conn.send(command + ' ' + ' '.join(args))
    if request_responde_and_show_it:
        print(conn.recv())
```

## Dynamically declare functions

Now, knowing this, we can dynamically declare functions for each of our commands.

To dynamically declare functions with a varying number of arguments, I found [this](https://snipplr.com/view/17819) approach, but I could not manage to make it work (I know `function.func_code` has now changed to `function.__code__` and `function.func_globals` to `function.__globals__`, but still).

So, the approach I found to work is using `exec()` along with multiline-strings:

```py
function_name = 'add_nark'
args = ('name', 'path')
# Create a string contaning the arguments separated by commas
args_code_str = f'{args}'.replace("'", '').replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
# Declare function on local scope
exec(f'''
def {function_name}({args_code_str}):
    # do stuff here
''')
```

## Annotating functions dynamically

Annotating a function like this:

```py
@my_decorator('some_argument')
def my_function():
    pass
```

is equivalent to:

```py
def my_function():
    pass
my_function = my_decorator('some_argument')(my_function)
```

## Altogether

```py
from multiprocessing.connection import Client
from collections import namedtuple

import click

Command = namedtuple(
    'Command',
    (
        'cli_command',
        'serv_command',
        'args',
        'request_responde_and_show_it'
    )
)

COMMANDS = (
    Command(
        cli_command='add_nark',
        serv_command='add',
        args=('name', 'path'),
        request_responde_and_show_it=False
    ),
    Command(
        cli_command='remove_nark',
        serv_command='remove',
        args=('name',),
        request_responde_and_show_it=False
    ),
    Command(
        cli_command='change_path',
        serv_command='change_path',
        args=('name', 'path'),
        request_responde_and_show_it=False
    ),
    Command(
        cli_command='get_path',
        serv_command='get_path',
        args=('name',),
        request_responde_and_show_it=True
    ),
    Command(
        cli_command='list_runs',
        serv_command='list',
        args=(),
        request_responde_and_show_it=True
    ),
)


@click.group()
def cli():
    pass


def send_command_to_server(command, args, request_responde_and_show_it):
    print(f'called send_command_to_server with: {command}, {args}, {request_responde_and_show_it}')
    with Client(ADDRESS) as conn:
        conn.send(command + ' ' + ' '.join(args))
        if request_responde_and_show_it:
            print(conn.recv())


def transform_args_to_code_str(args):
    return f'{args}'.replace("'", '').replace('(', '').replace(')', '')


def create_function(command):
    args_code_str = transform_args_to_code_str(command.args)
    # Declare function on local scope
    exec(f'''
def {command.cli_command}({args_code_str}):
    send_command_to_server('{command.serv_command}', ({args_code_str}),
        {command.request_responde_and_show_it})
''')
    created_function = vars()[command.cli_command]
    return created_function


def create_cli_command(command):
    created_function = create_function(command)
    # Equivalent to annotating the created function with @cli.command()
    cli_command = cli.command()(created_function)
    for arg in command.args:
        # Equivalent to annotating cli_command with @click.argument('someargument')
        cli_command = click.argument(arg)(cli_command)


def create_cli_commands(commands):
    for command in commands:
        create_cli_command(command)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_cli_commands(COMMANDS)
    cli()
```

Now, if you wished to, you could even extract the `COMMANDS` to a json file, so you  don't even have to worry about this script when modifying the server

Comment: Thank you so much for this great contribution, the answers I have gotten so far are a lot for me to understand so might take a bit for me to follow up.

Comment: This is already a really big improvement! After thinking about it I had some ideas and would love to hear your feedback: (1) Instead of sending a string I could send a dict with the arguments (2) Maybe I could build the named tuple in the daemon and send it to the client after it first connects (3) If I can send the tuples over, maybe I can instead try to build the whole cli() function in the daemon and send it over to the client

Comment: regarding (2) and (3) I found this library https://google.github.io/python-fire/ which can turn python objects in to a cli so maybe I can use a similar approach to derive the cli from my functions

Comment: @sev Question 1 - Yes, that is probably a good idea. Send the whole command as json. That will make it easier to parse in the server, and also easier to read/debug the code. Question 2 - That sounds interesting. That way, you would only declare the messages structure once, and the client wouldn't even need to know what the server commands are. However, I would then stop using `cli-command` names (`add-nark`) different from the `server-command` names (`add`). As that would mean the server needs to know part of the client's logic.

Comment: @sev Question 3 - I would definetly not build the cli in the server. Then, what is even the point of having a client and a server? The client logic (presentation, in this case), needs to be separated from the server logic (actual processing)

Comment: @sev Regarding the use of the `fire` module, that would take away the hustle of adding decorators for each of the command argument. However, I don't know if it would reduce the client's complexity. Although we would no longer need to add those decorators, we would have to declare all methods inside a class, to pass it onto `fire.Fire`. And that would make the dinamic function declaration's more complex, which already is the hardest part to debug in the code, so you probably don't want to do that

Comment: Regarding (3) What I (kind of) meant to say was I could write a function which takes another function as an argument and returns the corresponding command tuple. And maybe I could look at the fire library to see how they accomplish this task

Comment: @sev Actually, now that I think about it, what you are doing is RPC (Remote Procedure Call) through a cli. So, maybe you could actually use `xmlrpc` (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xmlrpc.client.html#xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy.system.methodHelp)), and register the server proxy through `fire`. That would probably make your client about 10 lines of code!

Comment: I tried doing this but am running in to some problems https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67929141/using-rpc-to-create-cli-client-for-controlling-daemon

Answer (score 1):

## In your daemon file:

- You are writing getters and setters which are not *pythonic* because there is no `private` keyword in python and all attributes are public. Python prefers using [@property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) decorator for meaningful getters and setters, which is one of many kind of [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties), which might do validation, logging or other tasks before getting or setting the value.

```py
def valid_path(path):
    """Checks if path is valid"""
    pass

class Nark:
    def __init__(self, folder_path):
        # I did not prefix the attribute with an underscore;
        # so the user of the class when accessing gets redirected to the property,
        # and cannot access that attribute without
        # messing with the internal workings of the class like __dict__
        self.path = folder_path
    
    @property
    def path(self):
        return self.path
        
    @path.setter
    def path(self, foldr_path):
        if not valid_path(folder_path):
            raise ValueError("Not a valid path")

        self.path = folder_path
```

You can even wrap the validation in a [decorator](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/), to abstract it.

```py
from functools import wraps

def valid_path(path):
    """Checks if path is valid"""
    pass

def path_must_be_valid(func):
    @wraps(func)    
    def inner(self, path):
        if not valid_path(path):
            raise ValueError("Path must satisfy certain properties")
        
        return func(self, path)
    return inner


class Nark:
    def __init__(self, folder_path):
        # I did not prefix the attribute with an underscore;
        # so the user of the class when accessing gets redirected to the property,
        # and cannot access that attribute without
        # messing with the internal workings of the class like __dict__
        self.path = folder_path
    
    @property
    def path(self):
        return self.path
        
    @path.setter
    @path_must_be_valid
    def path(self, foldr_path):
        self.path = folder_path
```

- I think creating a `NarkPool` class is not useful; because the `Nark` class itself does validation, you can just store the `Nark`s in a `dict`.
- You are not handling the exceptions that might happen if a key is not in the `narkdict`, for example: if you try to access a path that doesn't exists it will throw and exception and the daemon will terminate.

You can use the `get` method on `dict`s, which accepts a default argument to be returned if the key is not found in the `dict`.

Or you can use a `try` `except` block to handle the `exception`.

- When using `if`s in python all `if`s are executed so
  you are checking the command type 5 times, you can use `elif` which will stop checking other branches if one of them is executed.

```py
narks = {}

while True:
    conn = listener.accept()
    print ('connection accepted from', listener.last_accepted)
    while True:
        msg = conn.recv()
        # Python has a neat feature called unpacking values from sequences
        try:
            command, path, *additional_params = msg.split(' ')  # command input would be eg. add <name> <path>
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid command")
        try:
            # Manually define action to be taken based on each command
            if command == 'add':
                narks[path] = Nark(additional_parameters[1])
            elif command == 'remove':
                narks.pop(path)
            elif command == 'change_path':
                narks[path].path = additional_parameters[1]
            elif command == 'get_path':
                conn.send(narks[path])
            elif command == 'list':
                conn.send(narks.keys())
            else:
                print(f"I do not recognize the command {command}")
            
        except KeyError:
            print(f"Path {path} is not valid")

        if msg:
            conn.close()
            break

listener.close()
```

- I would suggest using a tools like [pylint](https://www.pylint.org/), [pyflakes](https://github.com/PyCQA/pyflakes) or [black](https://github.com/ambv/black); to autoformat and lint your code.

## In your client file

Your client code is small, so it does not need a lot of changes.

The only thing that I suggest you do, is noticing the similarities between functions and abstract it either using a [decorator](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/) or a [higher order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function).

I hope my answer has helped you in any useful way.

**Cheers**.

Comment: I think that here, the `@property` offers nothing of value over a plain member variable - for the reasons you've already described. It's just a fancier getter/setter.

Comment: Thank you so much for this great contribution, the answers I have gotten so far are a lot for me to understand to might take a bit for me to follow up. I have now started using pylint and black and also put a github action which uses them to check for code quality now.

Comment: first question: why would I use `nark_pool` to check the validity of the inputs rather than just checking in `nark` itself?

Comment: @sev After thinking for a while, I think your approach is better, because the `Nark` class itself should be responsible for validating the paths.

I will edit the answer to reflect the changes.